# R regular expression matching with reserved characters

Tags: r, regex, pattern-matching

I want to process lines of my data frame, I got this pattern in each line

```
x= RPA4|RP1-117P191
```

and I want this

```
 RPA4
```

Everything after the pipe removed

I tried with gsub, trying to get only the first part of the match

```
 gsub("^(\\.+)|*$", "\\1", x)
```

and I got the same. Could you help me please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
gsub("\\|.*", "", x)
```

this replaces everything after `|` with an empty string.

You used `\\.+` which matches the character `.` instead of any character.
Also you use `.+` which is greedy, so you should use `.+?` to not capture everything until the end. The pipe character `|` means "or" in a regular expression, so you need to escape with `\\|` to match the actual character.

Another solution (closer to your attempt) could be:

```
gsub("^(.+?)\\|.+", "\\1", x)
```